# Why is the conjugate alteration of the Mandelbrot set (the tricorn) also known as the "Mandelbar" set?

Tags: terminology, fractals

I am currently working with a shader rendering that deals with higher powers of the Mandelbrot set, [image: z_n+1)]. I understand that the conjugate of the first parameter of this set,[image], also known as the *tricorn*, is called the *mandelbar* set.

This is almost certainly some kind of a play on words; but while I've encountered multiple sources using this terminology, I'm not personally getting it. Can anyone explain why the tricorn is also referred to as this? Where is the *-bar* suffix coming from?

Thanks.

Comment: Look up "z bar math" The symbol $\overline z$ is often pronounced "z bar"

Comment: Thank you! Would you turn that into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I assume you mean $z_{n+1} = z_n^2+C$ with subscript $n$ on the $z$.

Comment: Indeed, that is what i meant to convey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up "z bar math" . The symbol $\overline z$ is often pronounced "z bar"